# Why did Blake draw the Batman symbol on things?

Tags: dc, batman, nolan-batman-trilogy, the-dark-knight-rises

In the Dark Knight Rises, after

> Bane takes over Gotham City and traps most of the police force under the city,

there are several occasions where Blake draws the Batman sign in chalk on buildings and things. Why does he do that?

Comment: Related: [Why does Blake draw the Batman symbols all over town?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/3453/49)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**His basic goal was to give the people hope that Batman would return. Granted, people were not moving around much, but when they did, he hoped they would see this icon and know that people were still willing, able and were resisting the occupation of Gotham by Bane.**

[image: Batsignal in the sky over Gotham]

- Such symbols were meant to inspire hope in the populace, promoting the idea that Batman could be anyone. Indeed, this becomes the central theme at the end of the movie when Blake is given the keys to the Batcave.
- Yes, they were small and apparently innocuous, but symbols have a strong capacity for promoting, inspiring and often fomenting revolution.
- It was unfortunate the movie did not promote the People of Gotham, rising up (along with the police) and taking back the streets. (If they did, it was not readily apparent to me.)
- The power of the symbol is derived from Batman's use of it himself, in the Bat-signal, formerly seen in the skies of Gotham, in flaming symbols he would leave at scenes, and famously in the display he made on the bridge announcing to his return to the battle.

A curious aside, I notice the image drawn by Blake does have a strong resemblance to the chest icon of that famed first Robin, Dick Grayson who is now know by a name he has made his own, Nightwing. Perhaps a foreshadowing, a sign of things to come? We know that Nolan has vowed never to return, so it may have been a nod to comic fans of a possible future we may never see in the Nolanverse. Replace the bat ears with a bird's head. Maybe it's just a coincidence, maybe not.

[image: Batman/Nightwing logos]

Comment: I've seen that last image rumor going around, but to be honest birds and bats are both winged creatures, and there are only so many ways to draw a silhouette.

Comment: I added it only as an aside. Since the Nolanverse is dead, such speculation is food for thought, nothing more. It wouldn't be "our" Nightwing anyway...

Answer (score -2):

he put the symbol on the buildings to mark the cargo trucks they where following so they knew the route so they could find the bomb and help.